# Gap between images and texts

Tags: html

I have a problem where there is a big gap between my images and texts.

I have this code:

```html
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
<li value="1"><b>View the label of the nodes</b></li>
</ol></br>
<br/><br/>
<figure><img src="images/tut/ft1.gif" alt="feature_1" style="float:left"></figure>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
<li value="2"><b>Highlight the nodes</b></li>
</ol></br>
```

And it will turn out like this:

[image]

I have to put the `<br/>` to allow the next list to be properly positioned under the image. If not, it will be really messy.

Here is the css :

```css
    figure {
    display: block;
    }

    figure img {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    }

    figure figcaption {
    align: center;
    }

    b {
    font-weight:bold;
    }

    i {
    font-style:italic;
    }

    p {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 150%;
    }
```

People suggested to put `display:block` or remove any space between tags but it still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gap is due to the `<br />`s. Since you're using them to `clear`, I would suggest:

1) Remove all the `<br />`

2) Remove the `float` on your image (both as style and in CSS)

3) Center image (I used `margin: 0 auto`)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xn9bf5od/

Comment: Tried your method but still does not working. I wonder if this have something to do in the css file that I have? But any css in the page will overwrite that right?

Comment: @kaixasK - Yes, that's correct. When you removed the `br`s, was it not working because the list looked bad?

Comment: yeah the second list positioned to the right of the img, not under it.

Comment: @kaixasK - Could you try adding `ol { clear: both !important}` to your CSS? If that clears it, you probably have some CSS that's being applied elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove all the br tags.

Then, add following style

```
figure {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get any changes when trying this method.. should i delete `float` as well?

Comment: I tested your code and it didn't need to remove float. But if it's not working on yours you are probably using other styles in parent elements or something like this.